# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \int_{x}^{1}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt = f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Prove that
>
> $$ \lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \int_{x}^{1}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt = f(0). $$

I tried substituting $z = t^2$ and integrating by parts to see if something useful pops up, but it lead me nowhere.

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Substitutions and integration by parts

Comment: Can you show us your work by editing the question?

Comment: Maybe use l'Hopital?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hospital's Rule

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \int_{x}^{1}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt=\lim_{x\to0^{+}} \frac{ -\int_{1}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt}{\frac 1x}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}} \frac{-\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=f(0)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question. We can use L'Hospital's Rule if nominator and denominator both go to infinity. Denominator obviously goes to positive infinity, but how can you know that numerator also goes to positive infinity?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,1]$. This will guarantee that the numerator goes to infinity.

Comment: @CYAries thats not true, if $f\equiv 0$ then the numerator is just 0. I recall though that l'Hôpital can be used even if the numerator is finite in the case when the denominator is $+\infty$

Comment: @CalvinKhor My mistake. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

(Proof without l'Hôpital.)
$$x\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = x\int_x^1\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t^2}dt + f(0)x\int_x^1\frac{dt}{t^2}$$
and $x\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t^2}dt = x(\frac1x - 1) = 1-x \to 1.$

So without loss $f(0)=0$ and we want to show $I=x\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt \to 0$. Note that we can replace the upper integral limit $1$ by any fixed $x_0$, since as $x\to 0+$, $$x \int_{x_0}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^2} \to 0.$$ Note then 
$$ \left|x\int_x^{x_0}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt \right| ≤ x\sup_{t\in[0,x_0]} |f(t)|\int_x^{x_0} \frac{dt}{t^2} = x\sup_{t\in[0,x_0]} |f(t)| \left(\frac1x-\frac{1}{x_0}\right) \to \sup_{t\in[0,x_0]} |f(t)|$$
By choosing $x_0\ll 1$  (using the continuity at 0) and combining the above estimates appropriately, we obtain the result.

PS if you want to use a change of variables, I think you should set $s=1/t$, $F(s)=f(t)$, and $X=1/x$, then $ds = -dt/t^2$, so
$$ I=-x\int_{1/x}^1 F(s)ds = \frac{1}{X}\int_1^X F(s)ds. $$